# Laravel Database unique key between different fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm building a website in laravel.
The user table has two email fields, an 'email' field and a 'new_email' field. When the user wants to change emails, it gets stored in the 'new_email' first, then when the user confirms it updates the 'email' field.

All good, but I want to restrict the 'new_email' field to be unique when comparing to the 'email' field. So that no user could change his email to an existing user. I'll do the check on the php side too, but I want the database to restrict that.. so I tried the following:

```
    Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
        $table->string('new_email')->unique('email')->nullable();
    });
```

Didn't work out, I still can add an email to the 'new' field, even when it's alerady on the email..

So, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't do this with by schema reinforcement, indexes don't work across columns. You need to do it with a similar mechanism to password request, simply check that the address you want to use isn't in use before creating it and make sure there's no valid change request for that email isn't in use before and after acting on the request. You might want a separate table for these rather than adding extra columns as well

Comment: You'll need to do that on application level - see http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation and unique validator

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using Request in Laravel,

```
/**
 * Class ChangeEmailRequest
 * @package App\Http\Requests
 */
class ChangeEmailRequest extends Request
{
     /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
     public function authorize()
     {
        return true;
     }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
    */
   public function rules()
   {
        // Here it will check for unique in users table fro email field    
        return [
            'new_email' => 'required | email |unique:users,email',
            // Considering you have user Id while updating    
            'user_id' =>'required | numeric'   
        ];
   }
}
```

// In controller you have to just use this request as below :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  use App\Http\Requests\ChangeEmailRequest;
/**
 * Class User
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
 class User extends Controller
 {
     public function changeEmail(ChangeEmailRequest $request)
     {
        // Considering you have user Id with it for updating
        $userId = $request->input('user_id', null);
        $user = User::findOrFail($userId);
        $user->new_email = $request->input('new_email', null);
        $user->save();
        return response($user);
    }
}
```

References : [Laravel Request](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests), [Laravel Validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation)